# Angularjs AppCtrl Resolve convention?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my application, I have some data that doesnt change often (Categories) that I need to access in more than one controller.

I thought it would be smart to wrap my 'Route' Controllers in an AppCtrl that would hold these categories. The problem I'm having is how would I setup my AppCtrl's resolve without having a route?

here is the code I have now, but Categories provider isn't defined:

```
'use strict';

var AppCtrl = ViewsDashboardApp.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', 'Categories',
  function($scope, Categories) {
    console.log(Categories);
  }
]);

AppCtrl.resolve = {
  Categories: ['$q', 'Category',
    function($q, Category) {
      var defer = $q.defer();
      Category.query(function(categories) {
        defer.resolve(categories);
      }, function(data) {
        defer.reject(data);
      });
      return defer.promise;
    }
  ]
};
```

But when I run this code I get :

```
Error: Unknown provider: CategoriesProvider <- Categories
```

Why doesn't the AppCtrl know about its resolve? specifically Categories?
Thanks.

Comment: What is the reason of using route resolvers instead of service/factory?

Comment: Could a service/factory also act as a resolve? preventing the app from 'completing' before the categories have been returned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Valentyn's Suggestion of using a Service worked out in a sense, and here is how I did it.

My Data Service looks like this, a factory for Category, and a service that provides the Categories.

```
angular.module('CategoryService', ['ngResource'])
 .factory('Category', ['$resource',
   function($resource) {
   return $resource('url');
 }])
 .service('Categories', ['$q', 'Category',
  function($q, Category) {
   var defer = $q.defer();
   Category.query(function(categories) {
    defer.resolve(categories);
   }, function(data) {
    defer.reject(data);
   });
  return defer.promise;
 }]);
```

Then in any route that needs Categories I can just requests the Categories service, returning the promise or the resolveed data:

```
resolve: {
 Categories: ['Categories',
   function(Categories) {
     return Categories;
   }]
```

This prevents my app from making the Categories request a second time when navigating other controllers.

Comment: You can just make categories return